# What is this defect in my basement slab?

Tags: foundation

I have very basic knowledge about house construction so I want to run this by you all for your opinion. I signed a contract for a new house build and the house foundation and framing is complete.

I found some visible issues with the basement slab and I was wondering if this is a cause for concern.

[image: concrete slab showing grape sized divots]
[image: close up of divots in concrete]
[image: extreme closeup of divots in concrete]

Comment: What are your concerns? It looks like the surface is being ground by the swirls, there looks to be some kind of droppings.

Comment: Those are not droppings. they are actually dents or breakage in the foundation surface.

Comment: That is a slab and not the foundation. If they are dents they can be filled with a epoxy made for concrete. A better photo may provide a better answer but with the grinding and divots your concrete guys were well below “professional” in my opinion.

Comment: I added a close-up picture. Thanks for your response by the way. The builder is KB homes they are known to be economical and cutting corners I think.

Comment: To tell the truth that is a really crappy job, those divots should have been filled when screeding. If they did have to grind to flatten it was not floated correctly which would have also partially filled the holes. 

I would suggest contacting the builder and having them remove and repair as that in no way is a professional job! Although legal issues are off topic those holes and the grinding are not professional results and my grandsons can do a better job.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think happened.

Builder poured the slab for the garage floor.

Then, after a bit, he came back and built the walls, roof, etc for the garage.

As part of that process, he had to brace the walls to ensure that they were vertical, before the ceiling rafters/roof members were added.  The bracing usually entails fastening a diagonal brace from the top of the wall to the floor, which in this case is the concrete slab.  The builder probable just "shot" a concrete fastener into the slab to secure the lower part of the brace, and the shot splayed the concrete or the concrete came out when the fastener was removed.

In either case, it's just a surface/cosmetic defect, and can be fixed with the proper patching material.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see a problem with your concrete slab.

The swirls you see are either trowel marks made during the pour to finish the slab or grinding on the slab to make it level.

The four small bumps in the middle are drops of something that will need to be removed to make the finish smooth.

I see a bigger problem with the height of the anchor bolts in the sole plate and the steel holddown. You evidently live in a seismically active area or high wind area and those bolts need to be installed correctly. I’d ask your architect or Building Official to check this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Do you think the anchor bolts should be taller and the plate thicker?

Comment: In order for the anchor bolts to develop full strength, they need to be lower. Your architect can tell you if the structural design requires full strength.